# Is it possible to have my gem write to it's root gem directory?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, filepath

I'm trying to improve my gem's favorites feature by writing to a file included in the gem. My current version works but it requires that the user have the created file in there current working directory for it to work.

I'm currently using `FileUtils` to write the file but have no clue if 1. this is even possible thinking maybe will have permission issues and 2. if it is possible how to have the path target successfully across different platforms and envs.

Current Code: In my executable

```
#creator    
if !File.exist?('usr')

  FileUtils::mkdir 'usr'

  FileUtils::touch 'usr/favorites.txt'

end


#writer
File.open("../ruby_doc_favorites.txt", "a"){|l| l.puts "some string"}
```

I would like something like ...

```
File.open("[dynamic_path_to_gem_directory]", "a"){|l| l.puts "some string"}
```

Comment: I - as a gem user - wound prefer if I had the change do configure where the file is stored or at least have that data in my home directory. And not share its data with all other users on the same machine in the gem itself folder. Furthermore the gem's files (what I would see as its source code) should not change after download. My advice is to separate the gem from its data.

Comment: I agree with *spickermann* - what you're going to achieve looks very inappropriate. If you're going to have some sort of the database for the gem, user should be able to set the path of that file manually, so if he re-install the gem, the data will persist. Alternatively, if you just need a temp file, you can use `Tempfile` instead.

Comment: It's also worth noting that writing to the gem directory may not work in some cases, such as users running system Ruby installations where the gems were installed by root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could get the gem folder is like so:

```
def gem_folder(gem_name, version)
  "#{Gem.path[1]}/gems/#{gem_name}-#{version}"
end
```

You would need to change the version each time you change the gem, but you're likely already doing that.

Unfortunately I have no guarantee that this works in a cross-platform way.

Example:

```
gem_folder('pry', '0.11.3')
# => "/Users/max/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pry-0.11.3"

# check find_files as a reference
Gem.find_files("pry")[0]
# => "/Users/max/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pry-0.11.3/lib/pry.rb"
```

You can hard code the gem name and version for your gem.

Comment: awesome will give this a try and return feedback, I saw that in .rvm and was wondering if can some how do something regex-ish but also noticed rvm saves separate folders for each ruby version. For instance if i install my gem on 2.3.3 it'll be in ~/.rvm...........ruby 2.3.3@global etc if installed on another will be that version folder might be another hurdle for this but thanks so much, will give it a go in a few minutes :)

Comment: Update: This doesn't work due to what I mentioned above `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/ruby_doc-2.5.0` that's the current path to my gem directory, I'm assuming if someone only has one version of ruby this would be the file path. will remove and test, maybe can add some condition statements in there and add both file path patterns , though, i'd then have to figure out the ruby `x.x.x` part 

Comment: Doesn't `Gem.path` give you the current rb version?

Comment: hmm weird... yea sorry i pryd in there giving what i want but didn't work , let me clean this up and retry .. back with feedback and current code

Comment: No worries ... many programs create a hidden folder in the home directory which you cann get with `Dir.home`. I personally have like 20 of these hidden folders created with various programs.

Comment: Update: ok so I noticed that was targeting the global folder and my gem is in the regular folder .. I changed to `Gem.path[0]` and it worked :) but now to see if this persists cross-platform. Either way thanks , giving me a lot to play with :) i'll do some testing and keep you updated